# ZooKeeper delete permissions enforcement understanding

Tags: java, permissions, apache-zookeeper, acl

```
[zk: 9] addauth digest user:defaultPassword
[zk: 32] create /test
Created /test
[zk:  33] create /test/can-delete null digest:user:xMNYqfrT373RREgAzmYepA2oLxY=:cdrw
Created /test/can-delete
[zk: 34] getAcl /test/can-delete
'digest,'user:xMNYqfrT373RREgAzmYepA2oLxY=:cdrw
[zk: 35] create /test/cant-delete null digest:user:xMNYqfrT373RREgAzmYepA2oMHb=:cdrw
Created /test/cant-delete
[zk: 37] delete /test/can-delete
[zk: 38] delete /test/cant-delete
```

(`localhost:2181(CONNECTED)` removed from each line above, to improve readability)

- The setup has 1 server and 1 client.
- To begin with I auth myself in command 9.
- I create a **test** node in 32
- Inside that I create a **can-delete** node with the correct ACL.
- Inside the same **test** folder, I create another **cant-delete** node with incorrect ACL permissions (If you see the last 3 characters before "=" of the digested password, I've changed them in command 35 compared to the on in command 34).
- I try to delete both nodes(can-delete and cant-delete). I'm successful in doing so.

I'm not able to understand why and how is it allowing me to delete **cant-delete** because the ACL does not match with authenticated ID:PASSWORD. I was expecting this to throw at me a **NoAuthException**.

Please help, Thank you.

Comment: I assumed ACL was for security. So what you mean is while deleting it only checks whether if the username is same or not. It does not really check for the password at all? I tried reading and that was not responded by with a **NoAuth**.

Answer (score 1):

The ZooKeeper [documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ACLPermissions) says that:

> ZooKeeper supports the following permissions:
>
> CREATE: you can create a child node
>
> READ: you can get data from a node and list its children.
>
> WRITE: you can set data for a node
>
> **DELETE: you can delete a child node**
>
> ADMIN: you can set permissions

Note that the DELETE permission applies to *child* nodes, not to the node itself.

This means that to prevent deletion of a node, you need to set an ACL (without the 'd' DELETE permission) on the *parent* of the node you are trying to protect (i.e. you need to set an ACL on the `/test` node in your example)